# Add protocol to struct after condition is met Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a struct called FoodItem and it has 3 properties

```
struct FoodItem {

  foodName: String
  foodAmount: Double
  amountMetric: String    

}
```

When the user add a food to the app he/she does it in 2 steps. Step one just requires those 3 things. However step 2 requires a few extra things...like amountOfSteps: Int, stepTitle: String...

```
protocol CookingInstructions {

  var amountOfSteps: Int { get }
  var stepTitle: String { get }

}
```

Is it possible to add the step 2 part as a protocol but add the protocol after step 1 is finished? so before step 2 the struct has no knowledge of the protocol but then it adds it?

In the end I just want step 1 to only require 3 things, and then step 2 to require a different few.

Comment: Why not adding `amountOfSteps` and `stepTitle` to `FoodItem` struct and make them optionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the conformance of a struct at runtime.

Maybe you could add another struct for step 2 and then a struct that contains your FoodItem and your CookingInstructions?

Like this:

```
struct FoodItem {
  foodName: String
  foodAmount: Double
  amountMetric: String    
}

struct CookingInstructions {
  var amountOfSteps: Int
  var stepTitle: String
}

struct Composite {
  var step1: FoodItem
  var step2: CookingInstructions?
}
```